Can I update the FEE and Withheld authority if I'm only the Update Authority?
I have a SPL Solana Token and I set as Fee manager and Withheld withdraw authority an EX team member.
I haven't the keypair of their account but I'm the only Update Authority of the token.
Mint and freeze authorities was revoked but Metadata is mutable and I'm the update authority.
Can I update now to a new Fee manager and Withheld withdraw aurhority?

With SPL Token, only the applicable authority can update that authority type. So for example, only the mint authority can change the mint authority, only the freeze authority can change the freeze authority, etc. In your case, only the fee manager can change the fee manager, and only the withheld withdraw authority can change the withheld withdraw authority.
